# Error de sintaxis mysql

Tags: mysql, sintaxis

Error  base de datos

Error: *#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca ' fuente int, refiere varchar(20), resul_llamada int, fecha_cita date, hora_cita ' en la linea 1*

Codigo:

```
create table Llenado 
    (id int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, nombre varchar(30) not null, 
    a_paterno varchar(20) not null, a_materno varchar(20), 
    telefono int(12), correo varchar, fuente int, refiere varchar(20),
    resul_llamada int, fecha_cita date, hora_cita time, acudio_cita int,
    cubre_perfil int, delegacion varchar(20), edo_civil int, edad int(2), 
    escolaridad int, institucion varchar, carrera varchar, genero int,         
    exp int, colchon int, transporte int, t_disponible int, credito int, 
    pago_credit int, buro int, monto int, imagen int, usuario_seguro int, 
    interesado int, psp int, logro int, energia int, adaptable int, 
    persistente int, tolerante int, sociable int, puntos int, estilo int, 
    ind_rendimiento int, validez int, gte_asignado int, 
    res_entrevista int, motivo_rechazo varchar, pp200 int, estatus int, 
    conexion int, oberservaciones varchar);
```

Comment: El fallo seguramente es definir un int con 12 dígitos (telefono int(12)), supera el intervalo de valores, bien disminuye el número de dígitos o bien utiliza un biginteger, este último ocupa mayor espacio. Otra opción es almacenar el teléfono como un varchar, puesto que es un dato que no se utiliza generalmente para operar con él.

Answer (score 2):

Con esto lo tienes

```
create table Llenado (id int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, nombre varchar(30) not null, a_paterno varchar(20) not null, a_materno varchar(20), telefono int(12), correo varchar(20), fuente int, refiere varchar(20), resul_llamada int, fecha_cita date, hora_cita time, acudio_cita int, cubre_perfil int, delegacion varchar(20), edo_civil int, edad int(2), escolaridad int, institucion varchar(50), carrera varchar(50), genero int, exp int, colchon int, transporte int, t_disponible int, credito int, pago_credit int, buro int, monto int, imagen int, usuario_seguro int, interesado int, psp int, logro int, energia int, adaptable int, persistente int, tolerante int, sociable int, puntos int, estilo int, ind_rendimiento int, validez int, gte_asignado int, res_entrevista int, motivo_rechazo varchar(50), pp200 int, estatus int, conexion int, oberservaciones varchar(50));
```

Tu problema era que no habías colocado un limite de caracteres en los varchar

Comment: Muchas gracias! no sabia que todos los varchar debian tener un limite, respondiste super rapido! me hace falta leer mas sobre sintaxis. Buen dia.

Comment: Perfecto. Si te sirve no olvides aceptar la respuesta para ayudar a otros de la comunidad